# How to work with MMFdata in c?

Tags: c, filesystems, operating-system

I'm having the following code,with compile errors,and I can't understand what I didn't defined well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <w3file.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 32

FILE * MMFdata; 
HANDLE hMapFile;
MMFdata = fopen(OsFileName, "w+");

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
FILE * MMFdata; 
HANDLE hMapFile; 

MMFdata = fopen(OsFileName, "w+");
fclose(MMFdata);

hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
                 INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
                 NULL,                    // default security
                 PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
                 0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
                 BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
                 (LPCTSTR)OsFileName);    // name of mapping object

   if (hMapFile == NULL)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).n"),
             GetLastError());
      return 1;
   }
}
```

Errors for:

IntelliSense: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
IntelliSense: identifier "OsFileName" is undefined
*What do I miss here ?*

Answer (score 0):

In your program:

```
MMFdata = fopen(OsFileName, "w+");
```

is a statement outside a function.

You cannot have statements with file scope, this statement must be inside a function body.

Moreover, the `OsFileName` identifier is not defined in your program.